# premade yet to be showed HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

lets say i've a form and in this form i would like to duplicate properties elements. now every property element is a div which contains some input elements. every time the user click on a button "add properties" i would like it to create another instance of this properties element

the question is where should i store these pre-made and yet to be shown to the user elements, in a way it would be easy to later modify it?
i'm using JS with jquery.

Comment: I tend to agree with the suggestions to create the element once, and then clone() it (and possibly remove() the clones).  But more context might be necessary - how complex is the element?  Does it contain one or more unique IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Will at least one property element already exist on the page?**

If so, simply select it, clone it and store it for later use.

```
var el = $('.your-element').html().clone();
```

Then later you can make copies of it.

If your element doesn't exist on the page yet.  You can still put it on the page in a div that isn't displayed and do the same strategy as above.  Or use a "template" format such as jQuery templates.

Answer (score 0):

I store them in a hidden template div at the bottom of the form like so:

```
<div id="field_template" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="prop_tpl" id="prop_tpl">
</div>
```

When the time comes to display it, I duplicate it in jQuery and set the `name` and `id` properties to prop_1 or prop_2 etc based on a counter of added fields.

Comment: so you're suggesting i should make an area in my page which will be used as a "bank" for this kind of elements ?